# Adjusting Value Range on x-axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

The value range on the x-axis is not using the values from my data. How can I adjust the range data to let's say 2000' steps, i.e. 0, 2000, 4000, ..., etc.?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar, 
        xmin=0,
        width=12cm,
        height=7cm,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={Datensätze},
        %ylabel={Unternehmen},
        symbolic y coords={Exasol,Steinhoff,Vonovia,Fraport,Gazprom,Apple,Berkshire Hathaway,Microsoft,Deutsche Bank},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (14587,Deutsche Bank)
            (22842,Microsoft)
            (10464,Berkshire Hathaway)
            (6035,Apple)
            (8127,Gazprom)
            (2822,Fraport)
            (129,Vonovia)
            (393,Steinhoff)
            (2439,Exasol)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: minimal example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just specify the `xtick`s.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar, 
        xmin=0,
        width=12cm,
        height=7cm,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={Datens\"atze},
        xmax=26000,
        %ylabel={Unternehmen},
        symbolic y coords={Exasol,Steinhoff,Vonovia,Fraport,Gazprom,Apple,Berkshire Hathaway,Microsoft,Deutsche Bank},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        xtick={0,2000,...,26000},scaled x ticks=false,
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (14587,Deutsche Bank)
            (22842,Microsoft)
            (10464,Berkshire Hathaway)
            (6035,Apple)
            (8127,Gazprom)
            (2822,Fraport)
            (129,Vonovia)
            (393,Steinhoff)
            (2439,Exasol)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove `scaled x ticks=false,` you get

[image]

Comment: Is there also a trick to put the small lines on the x-axis below the frame, like it is on the y-axis?

Comment: @larkee Just add `xtick align=outside`.

Comment: Changing the value of Apple to `(117851,Apple)` and `xmax=150000,` leads again to scaled numbers on x-axis higher than 99999. How can I fix that?

Comment: @larkee This is more a general comment, not specific to you, but why do so many users think that just putting some code fragments in the comments will make others understand what they are doing? The proper way to deal with a follow-up question is to ask a self-contained follow-up question, not to add a comment consisting of some fragments. Obviously `xtick={0,2000,...,26000}` does not lead to an appealing output when combined with what you said in the comment, so you must be doing something else, which is why you should post a self-contained question.

Comment: I agree and will create a new question.